# Where can I find sources for "com.intellij.openapi.graph.base" package of Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I was looking for the source code of com.intellij.openapi.graph.base.Command class here

https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community

,but it doesn't contain com.intellij.openapi.graph.base package.

Where can I find it ?

Comment: I would suggest to try IntelliJ `upsource` but it doesn't seem to be up and running...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, these sources are not available.

Taken from [here](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/288841)

> DEA's visualization support uses yFiles which is a commercial product, and
>   therefore it's not available in the Community Edition. In the Ultimate edition,
>   you can use yFiles in your plugins by means of IDEA's wrapper classes (the
>   com.intellij.openapi.graph package). There's no documentation for it, but
>   it essentially mirrors the yFiles API.
>
> We're no longer publishing javadocs as a separate download: you can simply
>   refer to the Community Edition source for any necessary information.